# Create 'versions' programmatically

Tags: version-control, lotus-notes, lotusscript, lotus-formula

Lotus Notes has a 'versioning' feature. You can set this to work in a mode in which the user needs to click `File->New->Version` to create a new version. I would like to use that functionality in a button on a form.

Is there a way (using `LotusScript`, `Java`, or `@Formula`) to create a new 'version' from the same form (besides creating a document and moving all of the fields over)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an @Command called [FileSaveNewVersion](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_FILESAVENEWVERSION.html) and the NotesUIDocument class has a SaveNewVersion method.  Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks. It seems my Google-Fu wasn't working today. This is exactly what I need.

Comment: Alternate ol' skool technique: use $Versionopt field in document: http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/0ecfaa780177563785256c54004b71b2?OpenDocument